# Manually generate antipodal grasps for grasping

Tags: robotic-arm, motion-planning, simulator, pose

I am getting into robot manipulation using parallel grippers, and am learning about it, and programming grasping different objects. I have the 3D model of the objects I wish to grasp. The next step is to actually generate antipodal grasps on the object. I was wondering if there is a tool where I can specify / annotate the grasp location on the 3D object. Then, using this I should be able to pick up the object in simulation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GraspIt! from the moveit ROS metapackage. I would recommend, however, deriving your own vector approach for grasping objects. You have to give your grasping software your gripper dimensions anyways, might as well do your own grasping algorithm.

I suggest you use vectors to place the origin of the gripper as well as how you wan to approach the object. These 2 separate problems can then be joined together to grasp objects.